# Ubuntu 15.10 Nvidia driver or updates?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

In software & updates-> Additional Drivers
I have the option of:
1)Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96 from nvidia-340 (proprietary)
2)Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96 from nvidia-340-updates (proprietary)
3)Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 from nvidia-352-updates (proprietary)
4)Using X.Org X server - Nouveau
5)Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63 from nvidia-352 (proprietary)

What is the difference between 1 & 2?
What is the difference between 3 & 5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between the normal and `-updates` versions is that the normal version is the stable version of the driver, while the `-updates` version receives experimental driver versions. The `-updates` driver is generally better for very new cards, but it does have the risk of not working at all, breaking the graphics completely until the driver is uninstalled.

So, if you have a newer card, go with 352.63 normal. It should work fine. If you have an older card, or the newer version doesn't work well, go with 340.96 normal. If you're feeling daring, use the `-updates` version to see if it works. If none of the drivers work, and you're not planning on intense gaming, stay with the generic `Nouveau` drivers.

I hope this is an adequate explanation. If not, leave a comment, and I'll attempt to expand.